# ExtJS 6 sliced Images for Internet Explorer 9

Tags: css, extjs, extjs4, internet-explorer-9, extjs6

I have upgraded my application to ExtJS 6 from ExtJS 4.I'm seeing 9 different folder in image directory of resource which used for `Internet Explorer browser 9` only.

I found that these are all `sliced images` which mainly used for Internet Explorer 9 browser only.

> Directories from ExtJS 6 Library which has sliced images
>   1) btn
>   2)
>   btn-group
>   3) datepicker
>   4) grid-row-editor-buttons
>   5) panel
>   6)
>   panel-header
>   7) progress
>   8) tip
>   9) window-header

In my application, I have my own custom theme for showing images other than these sliced images, my CSS also works good for Internet Explorer 9.My CSS exactly work and replace all that sliced images in Internet Explorer 9.

But, not sure why and from where my browser keep requesting for that sliced images for Internet Explorer 9 browser.

*Is there any way, I can stop requesting these sliced images from my application while taking sencha build ?*

I just want to skip these sliced image folder for IE 9 browser.I don't want to request them as I'm already using my customized images for same.

Comment: See: https://docs.sencha.com/cmd/6.x/advanced_cmd/cmd_build.html (`skip.slice`).

Comment: Does `skip.slice` skip these sliced images only ? I'm using sencha `ANT Build`..Where should I put this configuration ?